# Node.js - Результат запроса в бд из .then() в глобальную const

Tags: node.js, knex.js

Функция на php

Для более удобного разбора упростил , в действительности она сложнее, много джоинов, разбор массивов и сбор новых, обращение к апи сторонних хостов и т.д.

```
public function searchEvent(){
       $countryid = $this->input->post('country_id');
       $productid = $this->input->post('product_id');
       $colorid = $this->input->post('color_id');

       if ($countryid == null && $productid == null && $colorid == null) {
           $params = array('owner' => '0', 'active' => '1');
       }
       if ($countryid != null && $productid == null && $colorid == null) {
           // ключевой момент, надо получить результат запроса бд в переменную
           $country_name = $this->db->where('id', $countryid)->get('countries')->row()->name;

           $params = array('owner' => '0', 'active' => '1', 'country' => $country_name);
       }
       if ($countryid != null && $productid != null && $colorid == null) {
           // ключевой момент, надо получить результат запроса бд в переменную
           $country_name = $this->db->where('id', $countryid)->get('countries')->row()->name;
           $product_name = $this->db->where('id', $productid)->get('products')->row()->name;

           $params = array('owner' => '0', 'active' => '1', 'country' => $country_name, 'product' => $product_name);
       }
       if ($countryid != null && $productid != null && $colorid != null) {
           // ключевой момент, надо получить результат запроса бд в переменную
           $country_name = $this->db->where('id', $countryid)->get('countries')->row()->name;
           $product_name = $this->db->where('id', $productid)->get('products')->row()->name;
           $color_name = $this->db->where('id', $colortid)->get('colors')->row()->name;

            $params = array('owner' => '0', 'active' => '1', 'country_id' => $productid, 'country_id' => $productid, 'color' => $color_name)
       }

       $q = $this->db->ger_where('items', $params)->result();

       print_r($q);
   }
```

На php все до безобразия просто, теперь тот же самый код мне нужно реализовать в node js
Все бы ничего, но не могу догнать как результат выполнения запроса поместить в глобальную константу, типо

```
knex('users').where('id', 1).then( rows => { console.log(rows)}) // rows надо в глоб const userInfo
```

Различные вариации из гугла и док работают только внутри then() или внутри async/await функций, в общем внутри    {} или ()

Как в JS сделать аналог этого?

```
$country_name = $this->db->where('id', $countryid)->get('countries')->row()->name;
```

так, что бы переменная была глобальной и я мог использовать её во всем приложении, повторно не обращаясь за ней к бд и не обарачивая пять функций в еще одну функцию в которой доступна эта переменная

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: Определите переменную выше вашей функции. В .then() присвойте результат данной переменной `let data; someFn().then((res) => data = res;)`